# Как правильно писать "Телеграм", телеграм-канал или то же с удвоенными буквами?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать "Телеграм", телеграм-канал или то же с удвоенными буквами? Почему? Как правильно писать по-русски WhatsApp?

Answer (score 2):

С первым примером просто. Можно написать как вы предложили (**"Телеграм"** в кавычках кириллицей) или, что тоже корректно, оставить *в латинице без кавычек* (с этим названием так поступают чаще - русский автор так назвал). С удвоением буквы нет оснований писать: нет такого русского слова (переводом это не будет), а транскрипция (по звучанию) или транслитерация (по написанию) слова **Telegram** дают одну букву.

Чтобы для **WhatsApp** выбрать кириллический способ написания (латиницей можно написать как есть), нужно считаться с тем, что в смысловом отношении это непереводимый каламбур (искажение распространённого вопроса what's up? - "ну как?", "какие планы?"; App - сокращение от слова application - "приложение"), а формальная транслитерация здесь не имеет полезных свойств вроде возможности обратной транслитерации (неудобства: удвоенная "п" в конце слова затрудняет произношение, заглавную букву из середины слова всё равно убирать, а две первые буквы - заменять), поэтому для передачи разговорной речи и текстов умеренно формальных (в технических статьях лучше латиницей вписывать) я бы предложил остановиться на слове, сложившемся стихийно и удобном для произношения: **"ватсап"** (английское произношение ближе к "уотсэп", что не очень удобно).

Comment: Если "Телеграм", то почему не "Ватсап" (в кавычках и с заглавной)?

Comment: В кавычках надо (это не стало нарицательным), а насчёт заглавной буквы - не уверен: это в некоторой степени жаргонизм, понятный не всем владельцам телефонов и по нему трудно догадаться об оригинальном названии. Строго и безупречно в письменных текстах - оставить латиницу (без кавычек), а произносить название иначе заставить уже нельзя, да и не стоит.